# Invalidate Fields from Multiple Models

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, invalidation, formhelper

I have a form with multiple models in it. The validates in the models seems correct and the models are associated properly. But how do I invalidateFields from two models and pass the display error back to the form?

Code in my users)_controller.php is:

```
$errors = $this->User->invalidFields(array('fieldList' => array('password','cpassword','firstname','lastname','email')));

$this->User->set('errors',$errors);
```

But I have a Profile model chained like this:

```
$this->User->Profile
```

and want it to invalidFields to Profile.zip.

Answer (score 1):

you can use chained if clauses like described at
http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/10/09/about-php-basics-and-pitfalls/

basically, you use & instead of &&

so if you got a main model and related data:

```
$this->User->set($this->data);
$this->User->Profile->set($this->data);
if ($this->User->validates() & $this->User->Profile->validates()) {
    //continue
}
```

the single & makes sure that both conditions are executed (with && you would only trigger the first one if there was an error and therefore the validation rules would not get rendered for the related model)

you could also do:

```
$val1 = $this->User->validates();
$val2 = $this->User->Profile->validates();
if ($val1 && $val2) {}
```

this way they both get executed before you go into the if clause.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually setting errors in the invalid fields array, I would suggest to use the `$validate` array to set up validation rules.

You can define your own, complex rules if the built in ones are not enough.

Comment: this is using the validate, but how do the errors show in the form?

Comment: still doesn't answer my question, because the validate => only option in saveAll is not showing my Profile.zip error